# Symfony 2 onDelete setNull

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml

please can someone tell me how can I set onDelete: SetNull in Symfony 2? 
Here is example:

```
oneToOne:
    Company:
        targetEntity: Company
        inversedBy: id
        joinColumn:
            name: id
            referencedColumnName: contact_person
            onDelete:  ??
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Just quote the string and set `onDelete` to `SET NULL` like this:

```
joinColumn:
    onDelete:  "SET NULL"
```

more options: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-409